# How to detect if a given number is an integer?

Tags: javascript, numbers

How can I test a variable to ascertain if it contains a number, and it is an integer?

**e.g.**

```
if (1.589 == integer) // false
if (2 == integer) // true
```

Any clues?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a variable is an integer in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636536/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-integer-in-javascript)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
num % 1 === 0
```

This will convert `num` to type `Number` first, so any value which can be converted to an integer will pass the test (e.g. `'42'`, `true`).

If you want to exclude these, additionally check for

```
typeof num === 'number'
```

You could also use `parseInt()` to do this, ie

```
parseInt(num) == num
```

for an untyped check and

```
parseInt(num) === num
```

for a typed check.

Note that the tests are not equivalent: Checking via `parseInt()` will first convert to `String`, so eg `true` won't pass the check.

Also note that the untyped check via `parseInt()` will handle hexadecimal strings correctly, but will fail for octals (ie numeric strings with leading zero) as these are recognized by `parseInt()` but not by `Number()`. If you need to handle decimal strings with leading zeros, you'll have to specify the radix argument.

Answer (score 11):

This works:

```
if (Math.floor(x) == x)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the formal definition of integer:

```
Math.floor(x) === x
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
if((typeof(no)=='number') && (no.toString().indexOf('.')==-1))
```

Comment: That probably depends on your definition (and use case) of integer

Comment: Hmm. True. For inherently mathematical questions, I tend to think of them in terms of numbers and not numerals - hence, my comment above.

Comment: @MattBall It works for `8.000` too. When you invoke `toString()` on that number, you get `'8'`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Msyrh/

Answer (score 2):

Would this not work:

```
if (parseInt(number, 10) == number)
{
  alert(number + " is an integer.");
}
```

Comment: You should always include the radix parameter: parseInt(number, 10)

Comment: @Greg: not necessarily - one might want hexadecimals to pass; octals will fail as they are recognized by `parseInt()` but not by `Number()`

Answer (score 2):

Can use the function `Number.isInteger()`. It also takes care of checking that the value is a number.

For example:

```
Number.isInteger(3)     // true
Number.isInteger(3.1)   // false
Number.isInteger('3')   // false
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger

Answer (score 0):

you could either make use of javas parsing capabilities or as well try out the modulo operator %...

Answer (score -1):

There is a javascript function called isNaN(val) which returns true if val is not a number.

If you want to use val as a number, you need to cast using parseInt() or parseFloat()

EDIT:
oops. Corrected the error as mentioned in the comment

Comment: Just from the name of the function, I would think "isNaN" would return true if val "is *Not* a Number", which is what NaN stands for. Typo?

Comment: isNaN(val) returns true if val is not a number, but it  returns false for non-integer numbers as well so it won't solve the problem.