# How to check if a variable is an integer in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How do I check if a variable is an integer in JavaScript, and throw an alert if it isn't?  I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var data = 22;
            alert(NaN(data));
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: One posiblity here is to use [`parseInt`](http://www.bing.com/search?q=javascript+parseint&form=MOZSBR&pc=MOZI).

Comment: http://jsben.ch/#/htLVw - a benchmark for the common ways to do it

Comment: All the answers here are really outdated. Today, I recommend sticking to `Number.isInteger` which is the least hacky way.

Comment: @Benjamim what if the number is a string that can be converted to a integer? and in HTML everything is a string.. so Number.isInteger("69") is false

Answer (score 389, accepted):

Use the === operator ([strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity_strict_equality_())) as below,

```
if (data === parseInt(data, 10))
    alert("data is integer")
else
    alert("data is not an integer")
```

Comment: if you run your example through the above code it alerts out a as an integer and the other as not an integer which is the case... in case of NaN also the type of NaN is different from the type of the return value of pareInt().....

Comment: could you elaborate a bit? the "example" is only demonstrating that using parseInt yields worse performance than using typeof keyword and modulus operator. but I do see what you mean now about (NaN != NaN)

Comment: `parseInt(2.0) === 2.0`

Comment: @connorbode in javascript all numbers have the same type (there is no float or double), so `2.0 === 2` since the unnecessary decimal is just a different representation of the same number, thus `parseInt(2.0) === 2.0` is equivalent to `parseInt(2) === 2` which is true

Comment: @BlakeRegalia: Although being fast his method **does not** pass all possible values from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14794066/843732

Comment: Problem: set variable a = "2" then a === parseInt(a) returns false

Comment: This isn't a safe answer. The only cross platform solution for this is using the modulus operator as noted by François Wahl below.

Comment: parseInt transforms "40 is a number" into an integer 40, while "This 40 is stupid" is NaN.

Comment: This is a bad idea. See http://www.2ality.com/2014/05/is-integer.html (1.4). `parseInt()` coerces to string, for large numbers it won't do what you expect: `console.log(1000000000000000000000);` => `1e+21`. There's plenty of better ways, e.g. `const isInteger = val => val%1==0`.

Comment: The problem is that parseInt() coerces its first parameter to a string before parsing digits. Therefore, once the number becomes sufficiently large, its string representation will be presented in exponential form (e.g., 1e+21). Accordingly, parseInt() will then try to parse 1e+21, but will stop parsing when it reaches the e character and will therefore return a value of 1. Observe:
String(1000000000000000000000)
'1e+21'
parseInt(1000000000000000000000, 10)
1
parseInt(1000000000000000000000, 10) === 1000000000000000000000
false

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45037143/5470829

Comment: this is actually wrong for where data has non-number prefixes.. why not just:
`if (data === parseInt(data, 10).toString())`

Comment: I'd vote for this answer to be removed altogether.

Answer (score 596):

That depends, do you also want to cast strings as potential integers as well?

This will do:

```
function isInt(value) {
  return !isNaN(value) && 
         parseInt(Number(value)) == value && 
         !isNaN(parseInt(value, 10));
}
```

#### With Bitwise operations

Simple parse and check

```
function isInt(value) {
  var x = parseFloat(value);
  return !isNaN(value) && (x | 0) === x;
}
```

Short-circuiting, and saving a parse operation:

```
function isInt(value) {
  if (isNaN(value)) {
    return false;
  }
  var x = parseFloat(value);
  return (x | 0) === x;
}
```

Or perhaps both in one shot:

```
function isInt(value) {
  return !isNaN(value) && (function(x) { return (x | 0) === x; })(parseFloat(value))
}
```

Tests:

```
isInt(42)        // true
isInt("42")      // true
isInt(4e2)       // true
isInt("4e2")     // true
isInt(" 1 ")     // true
isInt("")        // false
isInt("  ")      // false
isInt(42.1)      // false
isInt("1a")      // false
isInt("4e2a")    // false
isInt(null)      // false
isInt(undefined) // false
isInt(NaN)       // false
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/opfyrqwp/28/

#### Performance

Testing reveals that the short-circuiting solution has the best performance (ops/sec).

```
// Short-circuiting, and saving a parse operation
function isInt(value) {
  var x;
  if (isNaN(value)) {
    return false;
  }
  x = parseFloat(value);
  return (x | 0) === x;
}
```

Here is a benchmark:
http://jsben.ch/#/htLVw

If you fancy a shorter, obtuse form of short circuiting:

```
function isInt(value) {
  var x;
  return isNaN(value) ? !1 : (x = parseFloat(value), (0 | x) === x);
}
```

Of course, I'd suggest letting the minifier take care of that.

Comment: @krisk - Upvoted for multiple solutions. Also performed a quick test on the 4 variants you provided: http://jsperf.com/tfm-is-integer - and determined that the short-circuiting solution has the best performance.

Comment: Since bitwise op returns 0 for a NaN, you could maybe dispense with the short circuit. I don't know however what are the respective costs of bitwising a NaN and isNan.

Comment: will it return true for 2.00 ?

Comment: It's returning false on 2099999999999999 :-*(*

Comment: @jkucharovic the bitwise OR operator is the culprit. Using the non-bitwise version will return true.

Comment: This makes '2.'  evaluate to true

Comment: @cyberwombat well that is a decimal number 2.0 :-)

Comment: @KubaBeránek I guess its unclear what OP wants. In my case '2' is a string and therefore not an integer.

Comment: @cyberwombat if you just want to check the datatype, typeof is enough (you can combine it with isNaN)

Comment: what if I want it to return false for the 4e2?

Comment: There is an issue in this code.  Running your fiddle and running values as low as 10000000000 starts to break the check.  However the max safe integer in javascript is: 9007199254740990, which is far larger.

Comment: it says that 0xf7f is true.

Comment: bitwise won´t work with numbers bigger than 32 bits and javascript can represent integers up to 53bits:

"The operands of all bitwise operators are converted to signed 32-bit integers" (MDN)

Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER is 2^53 -1

Comment: @krisk This Answer is Mentioned in the AngularJS Source file.

Comment: @JensonMJohn, found it: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/65f800e19ec669ab7d5abbd2f6b82bf60110651a/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1665

Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: `const s = Symbol('sym'); isInt(s); `  or 
`const o =  Object.create(null) isInt(o)`

These calls will throw an exception. They should be handled properly.

Comment: This returns `true` for string and number decimals. `4.00 // true` and `'4.00' //true`

Comment: Why was the !isNaN(parseInt(value, 10)) included. Also I was using typescript and thought of only including !isNaN(value) && parseInt(Number(value)) === value

Answer (score 159):

`Number.isInteger()` seems to be the way to go.

MDN has also provided the following polyfill for browsers not supporting `Number.isInteger()`, mainly all versions of IE.

[Link to MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger)

```
Number.isInteger = Number.isInteger || function(value) {
    return typeof value === "number" && 
           isFinite(value) && 
           Math.floor(value) === value;
};
```

Comment: MDN has the test on 9007199254740992 [removed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger$compare?locale=en-US&to=814547&from=679289)

Comment: This is the most straightforward and "correct" answer. I mean, JavaScript already has the method to check for integerhood. No need to write a new one. isNaN() tests for numericity, not integerhood.

Comment: @globewalldesk Maybe it answers the question "how to check if a number is integer" but  not "if a variable is integer". E.g. a string "1" for example.

Comment: @Onkeltem `Number.isInteger("1")`

Comment: @WalterRoman why? It returns `false`, while I would expect `true`. For example, parse a string like `product/24/edit`. After parsing you get an array like `["product", 24, "edit"]`, where `"24"` is most likely the integer of `24`.

Comment: Fix to the above. Should read: `["product", "24", "edit"]`

Comment: @Onkeltem `Number.isInteger(parseInt("1"))` returns true

Comment: I find it useful to do `Number.isInteger(parseFloat(value))` for form validations. Things magically change from number to string and back sometimes when dealing with forms.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler do you want to show the max. number for `Number.isinteger()`?

Comment: return Number.isFinite() && Math.floor(value) === value;     is more coincise

Comment: @WalterRoman `parseInt('123abc')` will become `123`, thus invalidating your method.

Answer (score 129):

Assuming you don't know anything about the variable in question, you should take this approach:

```
if(typeof data === 'number') {
    var remainder = (data % 1);
    if(remainder === 0) {
        // yes, it is an integer
    }
    else if(isNaN(remainder)) {
        // no, data is either: NaN, Infinity, or -Infinity
    }
    else {
        // no, it is a float (still a number though)
    }
}
else {
    // no way, it is not even a number
}
```

To put it simply:

```
if(typeof data==='number' && (data%1)===0) {
    // data is an integer
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? This checks for data types in javascript, `"1.0"` is a string, and is therefore not a number. Otherwise `1` will be the value of a variable if you set it thusly `var my_var=1.0;`, which is correctly identified by this function as an integer.

Comment: Soon, [`Number.isInteger()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) will work... until then, this is a good way to do it

Comment: Number.isInteger doesn't work for me. I must be doing something wrong. Blake's solution %1 works perfectly.

Answer (score 83):

You could check if the number has a remainder:

```
var data = 22;

if(data % 1 === 0){
   // yes it's an integer.
}
```

Mind you, if your input could also be text and you want to check first it is not, then you can check the type first:

```
var data = 22;

if(typeof data === 'number'){
     // yes it is numeric

    if(data % 1 === 0){
       // yes it's an integer.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32):

In **ES6** 2 new methods are added for Number Object.

In it **Number.isInteger()** method **returns true** if the argument is an integer, otherwise returns false.

**Important Note:** The method will also return true for floating point numbers that can be represented as integer. Eg: 5.0 (as it is exactly equal to 5 )

Example usage :

```
Number.isInteger(0);         // true
Number.isInteger(1);         // true
Number.isInteger(5.0);       // true
Number.isInteger(-100000);   // true
Number.isInteger(99999999999999999999999); // true

Number.isInteger(0.1);       // false
Number.isInteger(Math.PI);   // false

Number.isInteger(NaN);       // false
Number.isInteger(Infinity);  // false
Number.isInteger(-Infinity); // false
Number.isInteger('10');      // false
Number.isInteger(true);      // false
Number.isInteger(false);     // false
Number.isInteger([1]);       // false

Number.isInteger(5.000000000000001); // false
Number.isInteger(5.0000000000000001); // true
```

Comment: Note the comment on MDN that "The method will also return true for floating point numbers that can be represented as integer.". It depends on what you need.

Comment: 5.0 is NOT an integer, i will never use this for testing integers. thank you for pointing this out

Comment: it all depend on what you need. if you are checking the age field in a form Number.isInteger('10'); // false is not good.

Answer (score 31):

You can use a simple regular expression:

```
function isInt(value) {
    var er = /^-?[0-9]+$/;
    return er.test(value);
}
```

Comment: This was the one that worked for me because the other ones accept "2.", including Number.isInteger(). I only added a line to remove the leading zeros.

Answer (score 23):

First off, NaN is a "number" (yes I know it's weird, just roll with it), and not a "function".

You need to check both if the type of the variable is a number, and to check for integer I would use modulus.

```
alert(typeof data === 'number' && data%1 == 0);
```

Comment: should be: alert(typeof data == 'number' && (data == 0 || data % 1 == 0)); to avoid division by zero.

Comment: @Erwinus 0%1 is still division by 1.

Comment: @Phil, `(0 == 0 || 0 % 1 == 0)` will evaluate to `true`.

Comment: Oh, by the way `0 % 1 == 0` also evaluates to `true`! `%` is not division!

Answer (score 14):

**Be careful while using**

> num % 1

empty string ('') or boolean (true or false) will return as integer. You might not want to do that

```
false % 1 // true
'' % 1 //true
```

### Number.isInteger(data)

```
Number.isInteger(22); //true
Number.isInteger(22.2); //false
Number.isInteger('22'); //false
```

build in function in the browser. Dosnt support older browsers

**Alternatives:**

```
Math.round(num)=== num
```

However, Math.round() also will fail for empty string and boolean

Answer (score 9):

To check if integer like poster wants:

```
if (+data===parseInt(data)) {return true} else {return false}
```

notice + in front of data (converts string to number), and === for exact.

Here are examples:

```
data=10
+data===parseInt(data)
true

data="10"
+data===parseInt(data)
true

data="10.2"
+data===parseInt(data)
false
```

Comment: This seems like the smartest solution for my case (where I don't mind if it's an integer in a string). However: why not just go `return (+data===parseInt(data))`?

Answer (score 7):

Check if the variable is equal to that same variable rounded to an integer, like this:

```
if(Math.round(data) != data) {
    alert("Variable is not an integer!");
}
```

Comment: You can very easily fix this function's issue with returning `true` for `NaN`, by simply changing `!=` to `!==` and inverting the `if` blocks. This works because `NaN` is the only value in JavaScript that does not equal itself. For example, the new code should be `if (Math.round(x) === x) { /* x IS an integer! */ }`

Answer (score 6):

The simplest and cleanest pre-ECMAScript-6 solution (which is also sufficiently robust to return false even if a non-numeric value such as a string or null is passed to the function) would be the following:

```
function isInteger(x) { return (x^0) === x; }
```

The following solution would also work, although not as elegant as the one above:

```
function isInteger(x) { return Math.round(x) === x; }
```

**Note** that Math.ceil() or Math.floor() could be used equally well (instead of Math.round()) in the above implementation.

Or alternatively:

```
function isInteger(x) { return (typeof x === 'number') && (x % 1 === 0); }
```

One fairly common incorrect solution is the following:

```
function isInteger(x) { return parseInt(x, 10) === x; }
```

While this parseInt-based approach will work well for many values of x, once x becomes quite large, it will fail to work properly. The problem is that parseInt() coerces its first parameter to a string before parsing digits. Therefore, once the number becomes sufficiently large, its string representation will be presented in exponential form (e.g., 1e+21). Accordingly, parseInt() will then try to parse 1e+21, but will stop parsing when it reaches the e character and will therefore return a value of 1. Observe:

```
> String(1000000000000000000000)
'1e+21'

> parseInt(1000000000000000000000, 10)
1

> parseInt(1000000000000000000000, 10) === 1000000000000000000000
false
```

Answer (score 6):

Why hasnt anyone mentioned `Number.isInteger()` ?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger

Works perfectly for me and solves the issue with the `NaN` beginning a number.

Comment: Note that this is ES6, so [older browsers (like IE <= 11) don't support it.](https://caniuse.com/#search=isNaN) The docs above provide a polyfill.

Comment: Somebody did mention `Number.isInteger()`, 3.5 years before you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27424770/5208540

Comment: if we are going to catch an value from an input then check, Number.isInteger will always return false as the input value is of string datatype

Answer (score 5):

```
if(Number.isInteger(Number(data))){
    //-----
}
```

Comment: Same comment as below: [Not supported by IE and Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger).

Comment: @crisscross Now supported by everything except IE, which is only a concern if you're supporting legacy operating systems.

Comment: Number(data) would be zero if data is empty string or null, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#convert_numeric_strings_and_null_to_numbers

Answer (score 4):

ECMA-262 6.0 (ES6) standard include [Number.isInteger](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-number.isinteger) function.

In order to add support for old browser I highly recommend using strong and community supported solution from:

https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim

which is pure *ES6 JS polyfills library*.

Note that this lib require es5-shim, just follow README.md.

Answer (score 4):

Just try this:

```
let number = 5;
if (Number.isInteger(number)) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Number.isInteger() is not supported in all versions of IE browsers.

Comment: depends... if you care about preservation of Neanderthal Technology or if you want to promote new technologies. If you embrace the future then you would indeed adopt ES6 and do all you can to destroy IE. Like I do, like most do :)

Answer (score 4):

### What about large integers (`bigint`)?

Most of these answers fail on large integers (2<sup>53</sup> and larger): Bitwise tests(e.g. `(x | 0) === x`), testing `typeof x === 'number'`, regular int functions (e.g. `parseInt`), regular arithmetics fail on large integers. This can be resolved by using [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt).

I've compiled several answers into one snippet to show the results. Most outright fail with large integers, while others work, except when passed the type `BigInt` (e.g. `1n`). I've not included duplicate answers and have also left out any answers that allow decimals or don't attempt to test type)

```js
// these all fail
n = 1000000000000000000000000000000
b = 1n

// These all fail on large integers
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/14636652/3600709
console.log('fail',1,n === parseInt(n, 10))
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/14794066/3600709
console.log('fail',2,!isNaN(n) && parseInt(Number(n)) == n && !isNaN(parseInt(n, 10)))
console.log('fail',2,!isNaN(n) && (parseFloat(n) | 0) === parseFloat(n))
console.log('fail',2,!isNaN(n) && (function(x) { return (x | 0) === x; })(parseFloat(n)))
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/21742529/3600709
console.log('fail',3,n == ~~n)
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/28211631/3600709
console.log('fail',4,!isNaN(n) && parseInt(n) == parseFloat(n))
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/41854178/3600709
console.log('fail',5,String(parseInt(n, 10)) === String(n))

// These ones work for integers, but not BigInt types (e.g. 1n)
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/14636725/3600709
console.log('partial',1,typeof n==='number' && (n%1)===0) // this one works
console.log('partial',1,typeof b==='number' && (b%1)===0) // this one fails
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/27424770/3600709
console.log('partial',2,Number.isInteger(n)) // this one works
console.log('partial',2,Number.isInteger(b)) // this one fails
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/14636638/3600709
console.log('partial',3,n % 1 === 0)
console.log('partial',3,b % 1 === 0) // gives uncaught type on BigInt
```

#### Checking type

If you actually want to test the incoming value's type to ensure it's an integer, use this instead:

```
function isInt(value) {
    try {
        BigInt(value)
        return !['string','object','boolean'].includes(typeof value)
    } catch(e) {
        return false
    }
}
```

```js
function isInt(value) {
    try {
        BigInt(value)
        return !['string','object','boolean'].includes(typeof value)
    } catch(e) {
        return false
    }
}

console.log('--- should be false')
console.log(isInt(undefined))
console.log(isInt(''))
console.log(isInt(null))
console.log(isInt({}))
console.log(isInt([]))
console.log(isInt(1.1e-1))
console.log(isInt(1.1))
console.log(isInt(true))
console.log(isInt(NaN))
console.log(isInt('1'))
console.log(isInt(function(){}))
console.log(isInt(Infinity))

console.log('--- should be true')
console.log(isInt(10))
console.log(isInt(0x11))
console.log(isInt(0))
console.log(isInt(-10000))
console.log(isInt(100000000000000000000000000000000000000))
console.log(isInt(1n))
```

---

#### Without checking type

If you don't care if the incoming type is actually boolean, string, etc. converted into a number, then just use the following:

```
function isInt(value) {
    try {
        BigInt(value)
        return true
    } catch(e) {
        return false
    }
}
```

```js
function isInt(value) {
    try {
        BigInt(value)
        return true
    } catch(e) {
        return false
    }
}

console.log('--- should be false')
console.log(isInt(undefined))
console.log(isInt(null))
console.log(isInt({}))
console.log(isInt(1.1e-1))
console.log(isInt(1.1))
console.log(isInt(NaN))
console.log(isInt(function(){}))
console.log(isInt(Infinity))

console.log('--- should be true')
console.log(isInt(10))
console.log(isInt(0x11))
console.log(isInt(0))
console.log(isInt(-10000))
console.log(isInt(100000000000000000000000000000000000000))
console.log(isInt(1n))
// gets converted to number
console.log(isInt(''))
console.log(isInt([]))
console.log(isInt(true))
console.log(isInt('1'))
```

Answer (score 4):

The Accepted answer not worked for me as i needed to check for int/float and alphabet. so try this at will work for both int/float and alphabet check

```
function is_int(value){
        if( (parseInt(value) % 1 === 0 )){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
}
```

**usage**

```
is_int(44);   // true
is_int("44");   // true
is_int(44.55);  // true
is_int("44.55");  // true
is_int("aaa");  // false
```

Comment: `is_int("4aaa")` would also be true

Answer (score 3):

You could use this function:

```
function isInteger(value) {
    return (value == parseInt(value));
}
```

It will return true even if the value is a string containing an integer value.
So, the results will be:

```
alert(isInteger(1)); // true
alert(isInteger(1.2)); // false
alert(isInteger("1")); // true
alert(isInteger("1.2")); // false
alert(isInteger("abc")); // false
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `|` operator:

```
(5.3 | 0) === 5.3 // => false
(5.0 | 0) === 5.0 // => true
```

So, a test function might look like this:

```
var isInteger = function (value) {
  if (typeof value !== 'number') {
    return false;
  }

  if ((value | 0) !== value) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

`Number.isInteger()` is the best way if your browser support it, if not, I think there are so many ways to go:

```
function isInt1(value){
  return (value^0) === value
}
```

or:

```
function isInt2(value){
  return (typeof value === 'number') && (value % 1 === 0); 
}
```

or:

```
function isInt3(value){
  return parseInt(value, 10) === value; 
}
```

or:

```
function isInt4(value){
  return Math.round(value) === value; 
}
```

now we can test the results:

```
var value = 1
isInt1(value)   // return true
isInt2(value)   // return true
isInt3(value)   // return true
isInt4(value)   // return true

var value = 1.1
isInt1(value)   // return false
isInt2(value)   // return false
isInt3(value)   // return false
isInt4(value)   // return false

var value = 1000000000000000000
isInt1(value)   // return false
isInt2(value)   // return true
isInt3(value)   // return false
isInt4(value)   // return true

var value = undefined
isInt1(value)   // return false
isInt2(value)   // return false
isInt3(value)   // return false
isInt4(value)   // return false

var value = '1' //number as string
isInt1(value)   // return false
isInt2(value)   // return false
isInt3(value)   // return false
isInt4(value)   // return false
```

So, all of these methods are works, but when the number is very big, parseInt and ^ operator would not works well.

Comment: Having the following test `let possibleDataTypes = ['string', '20', '20.000','20.0001', [], {}, new Number(5), NaN, null, undefined, Infinity, -Infinity, true, false, 20, -20, 200000000, 20.000000, 20.000001 , Math.PI, 100000000000000000000, 1 + 1e-16];
let polyFillFunctions = [isInt1, isInt2, isInt3, isInt4, Number.isInteger];
possibleDataTypes.map((dataType) =>{console.log(polyFillFunctions.map((functionName) => functionName(dataType)))
});` display the possible data types' output in a compact side-by-side pseudo-tabular format. Inconsistent results arose.

Answer (score 3):

You could try`Number.isInteger(Number(value))` if `value` might be an integer in string form e.g `var value = "23"` and you want this to evaluate to `true`. Avoid trying `Number.isInteger(parseInt(value))` because this won't always return the correct value. e.g if `var value = "23abc"` and you use the `parseInt` implementation, it would still return true.

But if you want strictly integer values then probably `Number.isInteger(value)` should do the trick.

Comment: Note that this is not supported by IE; as stated  [here in the docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) I got my scrip halted because of this especially if the var you are checking is undefined

Answer (score 3):

```
var x = 1.5;
if(!isNaN(x)){
 console.log('Number');
 if(x % 1 == 0){
   console.log('Integer');
 }
}else {
 console.log('not a number');
}
```

Comment: After 29 answers, one would expect a bit more of explanations to make your answer stand out...

Answer (score 3):

### My approach:

`a >= 1e+21` → Only *pass* for very large numbers. This will cover all cases for sure, unlike other solutions which has been provided in this discussion.

`a === (a|0)` → if the given function's argument is *exactly* the same (===) as the bitwise-transformed value, it means that the argument is an integer.

`a|0` → return `0` for any value of `a` that *isn't a number*, and if `a` is indeed a number, it will strip away anything after the decimal point, so `1.0001` will become `1`

```js
const isInteger = n => n >= 1e+21 ? true : n === (n|0);

// tests:
[
  [1,                         true],
  [1000000000000000000000,    true],
  [4e2,                       true],
  [Infinity,                  true],
  [1.0,                       true],
  [1.0000000000001,           false],
  [0.1,                       false],
  ["0",                       false],
  ["1",                       false],
  ["1.1",                     false],
  [NaN,                       false],
  [[],                        false],
  [{},                        false],
  [true,                      false],
  [false,                     false],
  [null,                      false],
  [undefined,                 false],
].forEach(([test, expected]) => 
  console.log(
    isInteger(test) === expected, 
    typeof test, 
    test
   ) 
)
```

Comment: Good idea! I also like that you showed your tests but unfortunately this does not consider a String value of "0".

Comment: Hey @vsync, Not intentionally. I did originally upvote but decided to revert it back due to my previous comment. I must have accidentally double clicked it or something.

Comment: 1.0 is a float, not an integer

Answer (score 2):

Besides, `Number.isInteger()`. Maybe `Number.isSafeInteger()` is another option [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger) by using the ES6-specified.

To polyfill `Number.isSafeInteger(..)` in pre-ES6 browsers:

```
Number.isSafeInteger = Number.isSafeInteger || function(num) {
    return typeof num === "number" && 
           isFinite(num) && 
           Math.floor(num) === num &&
           Math.abs( num ) <= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also try it this way

```
var data = 22;
if (Number.isInteger(data)) {
    console.log("integer");
 }else{
     console.log("not an integer");
 }
```

or

```
if (data === parseInt(data, 10)){
    console.log("integer");
}else{
    console.log("not an integer");
}
```

Comment: This will produce the wrong result for `data=22.5;`.  Also both branches have `console.log("not an integer")` ::S

Answer (score 2):

The 'accepted' answer is wrong (as some comments below point out).
this modification can make it work:

```
if (data.toString() === parseInt(data, 10).toString())
    alert("data is a valid integer")
else
    alert("data is not a valid integer")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp for this:

```
function isInteger(n) {
    return (typeof n == 'number' && /^-?\d+$/.test(n+''));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function isInteger(argument) { return argument == ~~argument; }
```

Usage:

```
isInteger(1);     // true<br>
isInteger(0.1);   // false<br>
isInteger("1");   // true<br>
isInteger("0.1"); // false<br>
```

**or:**

```
function isInteger(argument) { return argument == argument + 0 && argument == ~~argument; }
```

Usage:

```
isInteger(1);     // true<br>
isInteger(0.1);   // false<br>
isInteger("1");   // false<br>
isInteger("0.1"); // false<br>
```

Comment: interesting, only work for small integer,failed on big Int.  isInteger(9000000000) returns false. the reason is bitwise operators treat numbers as if they were 32-bit signed integers.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.toptal.com/javascript/interview-questions:

```
function isInteger(x) { return (x^0) === x; }
```

Found it to be the best way to do this.

Comment: not a correct implementation, only work for small integer, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger for correct implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This will solve one more scenario (**121.**), a dot at end

```
function isInt(value) {
        var ind = value.indexOf(".");
        if (ind > -1) { return false; }

        if (isNaN(value)) {
            return false;
        }

        var x = parseFloat(value);
        return (x | 0) === x;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For positive integer values without separators:

```
return ( data !== '' && data === data.replace(/\D/, '') );
```

Tests
1. if not empty and
2. if value is equal to the result of a replace of a non-digit char in its value.

Answer (score 1):

Ok got minus, cause didn't describe my example, so more examples:):

I use regular expression and test method:

```
var isInteger = /^[0-9]\d*$/;

isInteger.test(123); //true
isInteger.test('123'); // true
isInteger.test('sdf'); //false
isInteger.test('123sdf'); //false

// If u want to avoid string value:
typeof testVal !== 'string' && isInteger.test(testValue);
```

Comment: Got minus probably because test is not a function.

Comment: @imlokesh what do you mean "is not a function"? oO
 I wrote i use "test method".

Comment: @imlokesh no problem, i just ask U cause i used it in production:) and i thought u found some bug:)

Comment: I use this: `const isInteger = /^\d+$/`, it's perfect, short, and solves the problem of 5.0 being incorrectly a valid integer by all the other methods. 5.0 is NOT an integer. There is a dot.

Answer (score 0):

I had to check if a variable (string or number) is an integer and I used this condition:

```
function isInt(a){
    return !isNaN(a) && parseInt(a) == parseFloat(a);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e267369d/1/

Some of the other answers have a similar solution (rely on `parseFloat` combined with `isNaN`), but mine should be more straight forward and self explaining.

---

Edit: I found out that my method fails for strings containing comma (like "1,2") and I also realized that in my particular case I want the function to fail if a string is not a valid integer (should fail on any float, even 1.0). So here is my function Mk II:

```
function isInt(a){
    return !isNaN(a) && parseInt(a) == parseFloat(a) && (typeof a != 'string' || (a.indexOf('.') == -1 && a.indexOf(',') == -1));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e267369d/3/

Of course in case you actually need the function to accept integer floats (1.0 stuff), you can always remove the dot condition `a.indexOf('.') == -1`.

Answer (score 0):

Lodash https://lodash.com/docs#isInteger (since 4.0.0) has function to check if variable is an integer:

```
_.isInteger(3);
// → true

_.isInteger(Number.MIN_VALUE);
// → false

_.isInteger(Infinity);
// → false

_.isInteger('3');
// → false
```

Comment: Manuel: That is true I'll add it to the anwser, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following function:

```js
function isInteger (num) {
    return num == parseInt(+num,10)  && !isNaN(parseInt(num));
}

console.log ( isInteger(42));        // true
console.log ( isInteger("42"));      // true
console.log ( isInteger(4e2));       // true
console.log ( isInteger("4e2"));     // true
console.log ( isInteger(" 1 "));     // true
console.log ( isInteger(""));        // false
console.log ( isInteger("  "));      // false
console.log ( isInteger(42.1));      // false
console.log ( isInteger("1a"));      // false
console.log ( isInteger("4e2a"));    // false
console.log ( isInteger(null));      // false
console.log ( isInteger(undefined)); // false
console.log ( isInteger(NaN));       // false    
console.log ( isInteger(false));       // false
console.log ( isInteger(true));       // false
console.log ( isInteger(Infinity));       // false
```

Answer (score 0):

After few successes and failures, I came up with this solution:

```
const isInt = (value) => {
  return String(parseInt(value, 10)) === String(value)
}
```

I liked the idea above of checking the value for not being NaN and use parseFloat, but when I tried it in React infrastructure it didn't work for some reason.

Edit:
I found a nicer way without using strings:

```
var isInt = function (str) {
  return str === '0' || !!~~str;
}
```

I think it's the shortest answer. Maybe even the most efficient, but I could be stand corrected. :)

Answer (score 0):

So many options in the answers.

`isNaN` can be tricky for pure integer and you still need other checks that make it obsolete.
`Number.isInteger()` isn't officially supported in IE (most wont care but there are stragglers out there).

I ended up writing something myself:

```
function isInteger(valueToCheck) {
    return typeof valueToCheck !== 'undefined'
        && (valueToCheck === parseInt(valueToCheck, 10));
}
```

### Test

```
let undefinedValue;
const testValues = [
    1,
    '',
    undefinedValue,
    1.1,
    '1',
    '1.1',
    '1-2',
    'bob',
    false,
    [],
    [1],
    {},
    {foo: 1}
];

testValues.forEach(value => {
    console.log(`${value} - ${isInteger(value)}`);
})
```

Results:

```
1 - true
'' - false
undefined - false
1.1 - false
'1' - false
'1.1' - false
'1-2' - false
'bob' - false
false - false
[] - false
[1] - false
{} - false
{foo: 1} - false
```

Some test values are overkill but their existence just shows clearly nothing gets through. You could possibly omit the undefined check in the function, but I find undefined things can be weird in JS so felt more secure it being there.

Answer (score 0):

With todays browsers `Number.isInteger()` is way to go just like many answers before this explained but I came across problem which is common and it ocured when I was building `API`.

So in `API` request, we receive properties as `string`, so `Number.isInteger()` will return `false`.

If we try checking it with `Number.isInteger(parseInt())` then values like `1.1` or `1.asd` will return `true`

To solve this problem I created function which checks if value is `integer` regarding it passed as `integer` or `string`

```
function isNumber(value) {
    return ([...value.toString()]
            .filter(x => [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0' ]
            .indexOf(x) >= 0))
            .length == Math.max(value.toString().length, 1)
}
```

`Math.max()` part is needed to handle empty strings

Answer (score -2):

You can use regexp to do this:

```
function isInt(data){
  if(typeof(data)=='number'){
    var patt=/^[0-9e+]+$/;
    data=data+"";
    data=data.match(patt);
    if(data==null){return false;}
     else {return true;}}
  else{return false;} 
}
```

It will return `false` if data isn't an integer, `true` otherwise.

Comment: That code will throw `TypeError: undefined is not a function`. `match` is a string method, you can't call it on a number, which `data` is. Even if you forced `data` to be a string, it still wouldn't always work because very large integers will give you exponent shorthand when converted to a string (e.g.  `var data = 1000000000000000000000 + ""` will give you `"1e+21"`

Answer (score -2):

Add class numOnly for the textbox,

```
$(document).on("input", ".numOnly", function(e) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\$]/g,'');
    if(this.value!=""){
      alert('Integer Number.');
    }else{
      alert('Not an Integer Number.');
   }
});
```

It works for me.. Try this one

You can use keypres,keyup,keydown etc., instead input.