# Check if input is number or letter javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I'm using forms in HTML and javascript. I would like an alert to pop up only if the user inputs a **LETTER** and clicks `submit`.

So I have the HTML code:

```
<form name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="return checkInp()" method="post">
    First name: <input type="text" name="age">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

And the javascript code:

```
function checkInp()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["age"].value;
if (x consists of any letters) // this is the code I need to change
{
alert("Must input numbers");
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Define “letter”. Is “é” a letter? What about “α”? If you mean Ascii letters from A to Z and from a to z, please say so.

Comment: You may also want to change the HTML. Switch `<input type="text" />` to `<input type="number" min="0" max="125" step="1" />`. In modern browsers this will check for an numeric input without any JS.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You can use the isNaN function to determine if a value does not convert to a number. Example as below:

```
function checkInp()
{
  var x=document.forms["myForm"]["age"].value;
  if (isNaN(x)) 
  {
    alert("Must input numbers");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Beware the empty string: `isNaN('') === false;` #jsrage

Comment: Don't do this, strings like '0xFF' and '2e32' will pass through this validation.

Comment: You cannot use this to check for numbers. It fails if an alphabet follows the number. Try this "3a".

Comment: And the craziest fact is `NAN` is also a number :(

Comment: @StormcrowSX what's about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636536/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-integer-in-javascript ?

Comment: this method is not reliable

Answer (score 56):

Use [Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to match for only letters. It's also good to have knowledge about, if you ever need to do something more complicated, like make sure it's a certain count of numbers.

```
function checkInp()
{
    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["age"].value;
    var regex=/^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    if (!x.match(regex))
    {
        alert("Must input string");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Even better would be to deny anything but numbers:

```
function checkInp()
{
    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["age"].value;
    var regex=/^[0-9]+$/;
    if (x.match(regex))
    {
        alert("Must input numbers");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you missing a `!` before `x.match(regex)` in  your second code snippet?

Comment: This is the cleanest solution

Comment: Or you mean `regex.test(x)` ?

Answer (score 14):

You could use the [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)  Function. It returns true if the data is not a number. That would be something like that:

```
function checkInp()
{
    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["age"].value;
    if (isNaN(x)) // this is the code I need to change
    {
        alert("Must input numbers");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note: isNan considers 10.2 as a valid number.

Comment: *isNaN -yes, that may be problem, is there any possible ways to input whole numbers only? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: For whole numbers only, use regex and take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `isNaN()`. It returns `true` when passing a value that is not a number.

```js
var data = 'hello there';

if (isNaN(data)) {
  alert("it is not a valid number");
} else {
  alert("it is a valid number");
}
```

Comment: isNaN(true) returns false

Answer (score 7):

A better(error-free) code would be like:

```
function isReallyNumber(data) {
    return typeof data === 'number' && !isNaN(data);
}
```

This will handle empty strings as well. Another reason, `isNaN("12")` equals to `false` but `"12"` is a string and not a number, so it should result to `true`. Lastly, a [bonus link](http://www.2ality.com/2014/05/is-integer.html) which might interest you.

Comment: Another reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636536/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-integer-in-javascript

Answer (score 7):

I know this post is old but it was the first one that popped up when I did a search. I tried @Kim Kling RegExp but it failed miserably. Also prior to finding this forum I had tried almost all the other variations listed here. In the end, none of them worked except this one I created; it works fine, plus it is es6:

```
    const regex = new RegExp(/[^0-9]/, 'g');
    const val = document.forms["myForm"]["age"].value;

    if (val.match(regex)) {
       alert("Must be a valid number");
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Just find the remainder by dividing by 1, that is x%1. If the remainder is 0, it means that x is a whole number. Otherwise, you have to display the message "Must input numbers". This will work even in the case of strings, decimal numbers etc.

```
function checkInp()
{
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["age"].value;
    if ((x%1) != 0) 
    {
        alert("Must input numbers");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
if(parseInt("0"+x, 10) > 0){/* x is integer */}
```

Comment: or simply `if ( (x >> 0) > 0 )`

Comment: Worked grand also, except there is still the issue with the decimal numbers. Thanks a million for the answer though.

Comment: Could you guys explain in detail how does it work? What does `>>`operator means? Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, it gives 32 for "32!" instead of an error.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest would be to create a `Number` object with the string and check if with the help of `isInteger` function provided by `Number` class itself.

```
Number.isInteger(Number('1')) //true
Number.isInteger(Number('1 mango')) //false
Number.isInteger(Number(1)) //true
Number.isInteger(Number(1.9)) //false
```

Comment: beware Number(''); //0

Comment: `Number.isInteger('1')` wont return true. it returns false. It will still read as string.

Comment: pass ```Number('1') ```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, I used @str8up7od answer to create a function today which also checks if the input is empty:

```
    function is_number(input) {
        if(input === '')
            return false;
        let regex = new RegExp(/[^0-9]/, 'g');
        return (input.match(regex) === null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and modern way is typeof (variable) if you care about real number not number from string. For example:

```
var a = 1;
var b = '1';

typeof a: // Output: "number"
typeof b: // Output: "string
```