# how can I make an input so there is 1 letter and 7 numbers with javacscipt

Tags: javascript

I want to change the input field so the user can only write 1 letter and then 7 numbers like s1234567.
I tried to make the input field numbers only but then I cant write the first letter.

```
       <div class="page" id="login-page">
            <h1>Aanmelden</h1>
            <input id="loginInput" placeholder="s1234567">
            <button id="loginButton">login</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: A possible solution is to make two boxes, one with only one character, another with only numbers and concatenate the result. Could this be done in your context ?

Comment: @gordon_freeman no it needs to be in one input box

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if input is number or letter javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042133/check-if-input-is-number-or-letter-javascript)

Comment: @ikiK not really because I need letters and numbers in one input box but it has to be in this order: s1234567

Comment: the user cant type like 1234567s, the s has to be at the beginning

Comment: So what, write your own JS logic using upper link. Check if first 7 characters are IsNAN and last one is latter... Or whatever you need...

Comment: another option would be to use regex to check for and strip incorrect characters, start with `/[a-zA-Z]\d{7}/g` as the correct pattern to check for

Answer (score 2):

You can use pattern attribute of an input element like so

```html
<input id="loginInput" placeholder="s1234567" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]\d{7}">
```

Keep in mind that will not match any non English characters like ą, ć and so on.

Reference https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: `{1}` is not needed (it does not have any affect) and it's `\d`, not `/d`.

Comment: i would suggest using [a-zA-Z] to only match english chars

Comment: I made a fiddle for you so you can see if you  copy paste the placeholder, its still not valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below pattern

```html
<input id="loginInput" placeholder="s1234567" pattern="^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{7}">
```

For more ref : [JavaScript RegExp Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Comment: no need for the `{1}` that is implicit and `[0-9]` can be written as `\d`

Answer (score 0):

You can check your condition on [keydown event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) and allow or disallow the key press

```js
document.getElementById("loginInput").addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    let keyCode = event.keyCode == 0 ? event.charCode : event.keyCode;
    if (([8, 9, 46, 36, 35, 37, 39].indexOf(keyCode) !== -1))//allow special chars
        return;
    let symbol = event.key;
    let length = this.value.length;// + 1;
    if (!(length === 0 && symbol.match(/[a-zA-Z]/i) || (length < 8 && !isNaN(symbol)))) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="page" id="login-page">
    <input id="loginInput" pattern="^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{7}" placeholder="s1234567">
</div>
```

Comment: interesting approach but it works flawlessly (on firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Hello mate I have built something similar. I think you have to form a regex more specific to your scenario and replace it in my code. [check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1m40ngka/)

Html:

```
<input id="loginInput" placeholder="s1234567" pattern="^[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{7}" oninput="myFunction()">
```

JS:

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById('loginInput');
console.log("script is running");
  
function myFunction() {
console.log("inside change");
  var content = inputBox.value;
  var pattern = new RegExp(/^([A-Za-z]{1})*[0-9]{0,7}/);
    var isMatching = pattern.test(content);
  console.log("is matching", isMatching);
  if(!isMatching){
    inputBox.value = content.slice(0, content.length - 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: your pattern will match any amount of letters or 0-7 numbers, it also matches on empty strings - this may be unintended behavior and you should revise your pattern.

Comment: yes @RozzA. If we could find a new pattern and change it this will meet the requirement.