# JS Closures, calculating the perimeter and area of a rectangle

Tags: javascript

Write code to "safely" calculate the perimeter and area of a rectangle.
The sides of a rectangle can only be a number (data type Number, values of other data types cannot be set), the value of which is strictly greater than 0. Code must be in Secure Closure format. **Why doesn't validation work in my code that values are strictly greater than 0 and how to validate that there are only numbers**

```js
function createPOWandS() {
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  var arr = [];
  arr[0] = function(newSum) {
    if (newSum >= 0) {
      x = newSum;
      y = newSum;
    }
  };
  arr[1] = function() {
    return 2 * (x + y);
  };
  arr[2] = function() {
    return x * y;
  }
  return arr;
}

var sqrt = createPOWandS();
sqrt[0](2, 2);
console.log(sqrt[1]());
sqrt[0](2, 2);
console.log(sqrt[2]());
```

Comment: You are calling the method with two numbers and you are only using the first?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042133/check-if-input-is-number-or-letter-javascript

Comment: What do "Locking" and "Secure Closure format" mean here?

Comment: Using a closure method so that there is validation

Answer (score 0):

I restructured your function to show the three functions being returned. What you have here is called a "thunk". A function that returns a function, except you are returning an array of unnamed functions.

To "reveal" what the functions do, I destructured the resulting array into a setter, perimeter, and area function.

I also added a try-catch error handling example for invalid inputs.

```js
const isNumeric = (n) => !isNaN(n - parseFloat(n));
const isValid = (n) => isNumeric(n) && n > 0;

const createPOWandS = () => {
  const state = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  return [
    (x, y) => {
      if (!isValid(x) || !isValid(y)) {
        throw new Error(`Illegal arguments: (${x}, ${y})`);
      }
      Object.assign(state, { x: x, y: y });
    },
    () => 2 * (state.x + state.y),
    () => state.x * state.y
  ];
};

// Invalid
{
  const [setter, calcPerimiter, calArea] = createPOWandS();
  try {
    setter('A', false);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
}

// Valid
{
  const [setter, calcPerimiter, calArea] = createPOWandS();
  setter(2, 3);
  console.log('Perimiter:', calcPerimiter());
  console.log('Area:', calArea());
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```