# What's my bug in this code?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have this:

```
if (dTotal % 1 !== 0 || nTotal % 1 !== 0) {
   //stuff  
}
```

and the variable nTotal is the number 0.2, but the stuff in the if statement is happening. I know that the two variables are numbers, not strings. I just want the things in the if statement to happen if **both** nTotal and dTotal are whole numbers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a variable is an integer in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636536/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-integer-in-javascript)

Comment: `0.2 % 1 === 0.2`, which you can test in a Javascript console

Comment: what is the value of dTotal?

Comment: dTotal has a value of 1

Comment: It's not really a duplicate, since he's not asking how to test for integer-ness, but rather why his `if` statement is not working, which is due to a typo (forgot to apply `!` to the `if` condition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is from @IsaacRay; you simply had the polarity of your test reversed.

The accepted answer, for what it's worth, is about ten times slower than using `%`.

You could also use `Math.floor` which is about as fast as `%`:

```
if (Math.floor(dTotal) === dTotal && Math.floor(nTotal) === nTotal) {
```

[`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) basically removes the decimal part of the number. By comparing it to the original number, we can see if the number is an integer.

You might be tempted to use [`Number.isInteger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) if available, but it is very slow; twice as slow as even `parseInt`, twenty times as slow as `%` or `Math.floor`.

JSPerf: http://jsperf.com/testing-if-a-number-is-an-integer

Answer (score 3):

```
if (parseInt(dTotal) == parseFloat(dTotal)
 && parseInt(nTotal) == parseFloat(nTotal)) {
  alert("success");
}
```

If both ARE numbers, then this will work.

Comment: I'm super new to Javascript, so I don't know much about it, so what exactly is that doing?

Comment: parseInt converts a string or integer to its integer value, so 1.2 => 1. parseFloat does the same, except to a float, so 1.2 => 1.2. When you compare the two, as parseInt always goes to an integer, they can only be the same if the number provided is an integer.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!(dTotal % 1 !== 0 || nTotal % 1 !== 0))
```

You need a NOT before the OR clause. Your original code was saying:

If the remainder of dTotal divided by one is not 0 (meaning its not an integer) OR
If the remainder of nTotal divided by one is not 0 (meaning its not an integer) then do something...

You want the opposite of that, so add the exclamation point as I have done.

Answer (score 0):

```
dTotal % 1 !== 0
```

That part is probably true, which is why the if condition is true. (You're using or (||) not and (&&))