# Validate textbox which can accept integer from 3 to 1440 or "Default" word

Tags: asp.net, validation

I need to do validation on text box such that it can only accept integers from 3 to 1440 or "Default" word.  range validator control does not work in this case and probably have to use custom validator control and jquery I am assuming.anyone with a solution similar to this?

Comment: Because the "default" value there is no ready implementation for it, but you can write your on custom validation attribute http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/mvc-4-custom-validation-data-annotation-attribute/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow below example for your requirement:

```
<input type="text" id="txtbox" runat="server" onchange="javascript:return validateRange();" />
```

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         function validateRange() {
            var txtVal = document.getElementById("<%=txtbox.ClientID%>").value;
            if ((txtVal >= 3 && txtVal <= 1440) ||(txtVal == "Default")) {
                return true;
            }
            else
                alert('Please enter a number between 3-1400 or Default');//Also you can set this message to an existing label
            return false;
        }

</script>
```

Comment: this works great thanks. how do you make sure this txtval is integer and not accept any decimal numbers?

Comment: I hope these links will be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636536/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-integer-in-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-to-check-that-a-number-is-float-or-integer

Comment: Please do mark the answer as correct, if it worked for you. Thank you :) @avi

Comment: I do not see any option to mark this as correct answer .How do I do that? :)

Comment: There is correct check beneath "2" upvotes marked near my answer. Clicking that marks the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom validation attribute

```
  public class CustomRangeValidator : ValidationAttribute  
    {  
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)  
        {  
            if (value != null)  
            {  
                string inputValue= value.ToString();  

                if (some if statement)  
                {  
                    return ValidationResult.Success;  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                    return new ValidationResult("Please Enter a Valid Email.");  
                }  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                return new ValidationResult("" + validationContext.DisplayName + " is required");  
            }  
        }
```

then in your class:

```
 [CustomRangeValidator]  
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

My question needed a validation for integers and all cases of default too. so i used following in addition to @ruchi rahul answer.

```
 if ((txtVal >= 3 && txtVal <= 1440 && txtVal%1===0) || (txtVal.toUpperCase() == "Default".toUpperCase()))
```