# Java validating Scanner Input with

Tags: java

How would I use InputMismatchException to determine if the value entered into the Scanner is not an integer?  Basically, if they enter in a word instead of an integer I need to use InputMismatchException to return a message.

```
while (true) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        try{
            Integer.parseInt(i);
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, " + i + " is not a number.");
        }

        if (i == 1) {
            System.out.println("1 was selected");
        } else {
            System.out.println("1 was not selected");

        }
```

Comment: the error would be thrown by the line `sc.nextInt();` not by doing `Integer.parseInt(i);` so put `int i = sc.nextInt();` inside of a try catch with that Exception and it should work

Comment: can you please post what you mean?

Comment: i have posted below.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code as such:

```
while (true) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    try{
       int i = Integer.parseInt(s);

       if (i == 1) {
           System.out.println("1 was selected");
       } else {
           System.out.println("1 was not selected");
       }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, " + s + " is not a number.");
    }


}
```

Changes:

- Note use of nextLine().  This is because it seems you want to use the input as part of your error message, and nextInt() won't let you do that.
- We can now move the i declaration inside the try block, along with
  the code that uses it, so we won't issue "1 was not selected" when the input was "ssss" or whatever.
- We use NumberFormatException, as that's what Integer.parseInt()
  throws when it can't parse an integer from the String.

Comment: that mostly works, but for the catch part it gives an error before compiling stating that 'i cannot be resolved to a variable'.  How would i fix that?

Comment: @user3586248 you need to declare it outside of the try/catch. Right under the line `Scanner scan`

Comment: Yes, if you want to use the input in the exception println, it needs to be declared outside the try block...  I'll change the answer to reflect that, though I wouldn't normally do that, as the InputMismatchException has a getMessage() which you could use instead.  (You may not like the message it gives, so changing it is fine, if you want).

Comment: i tried what you edited it to but now it gives an error: 'the local variable i may have not been initialized'

Comment: wait... actually, you can't do this.  i will only populate if it's an integer.  If you absolutely want to use the input in the error message, you'll need to use a string and parseInt.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i mean

```
while (true) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = -1;
    try
    {
        i = sc.nextInt();
    } 
    catch (InputMismatchException e)
    {System.out.println("Sorry, " + i + " is not a number.");}

    if (i == 1)
        System.out.println("1 was selected");
    else
        System.out.println("1 was not selected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to the programming, I think I got the code for your question.

```
while (true) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        try{
           int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
           if (i == parseInt(i, 3)) {
               System.out.println(s+" is selected");
           } else {
               System.out.println("Input value is " + s);
           }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, " + s + " is not a number.");
        }}}
        private static int parseInt(int i, int j) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }}
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636536/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-integer-in-javascript)