# +prompt vs prompt in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it good to use `+prompt` instead of just regular `prompt` in JavaScript if I want only integer numbers to be typed in my prompt window? Does it say something like that about `+prompt` in the JavaScript standard/rules ?

Comment: What is `+prompt`?

Comment: @SandeepNayak if I enter some strings into the prompt when using +prompt it will return NaN.

Comment: @SandeepNayak — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129137/what-does-mean-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

The [unary plus operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129137/what-does-mean-in-javascript) will convert the response in to a Number, not an integer.

It could give you a floating point value, it could give you `NaN`.

If you want an integer then you need to [check the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636536/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-integer-in-javascript) and then put in some error recovery for cases where the response is not what you want.

For example: If it is a floating point value, then you might want to just use `Math.floor` to convert it. If it is `NaN` then you might want to `prompt` the user again.

Answer (score 5):

Well this is what happen's when you add plus before prompt, i.e. as below,

Eg :- 1

```
var a = prompt("Please enter a number");
console.log(a);
typeof(a);
```

Now in **eg (1)** when you enter a number and if you check that in console, it show a number but as that number is in-between double-quote, so in JavaScript it's a string, that's what it will show in typeof too when you console that.

Eg :- 2

```
var a = +prompt("Please enter a number");
console.log(a);
typeof(a);
```

Now when you console the var a and `typeof` a of **eg(2)** the result differs as we have added + before prompt. So this time we get our prompt input value as number and not string. Try you will understand what I'm saying.

Comment: That's great!! Welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

The effect of `+promt("...")` is that the result of the promt command will be cast to a number.

This is a nice hack, but not a clean solution.

I would recommend to assign the user input to a variable, then check it and in case it doesn't match the requirements, throw an exception or error message.

```
var
    input = prompt("Please enter a positive number"),
    inputNum = parseInt(input, 10);

if (isNaN(inputNum) || inputNum < 1)
    alert("You did not enter a positive number.");
```

Comment: "to a positive number" — Incorrect. It doesn't force a positive number. `+"-22.134"` evaluates as `-22.134`

Comment: @Quentin is right, it just coerces the variable to a number but does not enforce any sign (don't be fooled into thinking the + operator has anything to do with positive numbers). You should correct this as your SO score gives your post high credibility and can more easily lead to the misinformation spreading.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

So putting a `+` before any data type converts it into a number.
I tried this:

```
typeof(+"100") ==> number
typeof(+"12.34") ==> number
typeof(+true) ==> number
typeof(+false) ==> number
```

Things got really weird when I experimented with the `undefined` data type. e.g.:

```
x = +undefined
typeof(x) ==> Number whilst value of variable x is NaN
```

Comment: That makes sense.  `parseFloat(undefined)` is NaN, just like `parseFloat('afije')`  But NaN is of type number.

Answer (score 0):

```
let theNumber = +prompt("Pick a number")
if (theNumber) {
    console.log("Your number is the square root of " +
    theNumber);
    }
    else {
        console.log("It is NaN");
    }
```

+prompt can be very useful when you want create password that contains only number

Answer (score -1):

`+prompt()` is just a `+` before a `prompt()`, it's like writing `+"3"` or `+"10"`. It just tries to cast the outcome to a number.

Comment: It will change the string the prompt returns into a number.

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, I noticed immedialitely

Comment: You haven't answered the question though.