# Validating a percentage variable. No decimal points, No negative numbers

Tags: javascript

This sounds easy but unable to get it to work.
I need to accept a percentage number from 0 to 100 with no decimal numbers, no negative numbers. 
How can I do this validatation?

```
if ((Pcomplete == "" ) || (Pcomplete < 0 && Pcomplete > 100)) {
  alert('Percentage field is required. You need to type a number between 0 and 100');
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Pcomplete can never be less than 0 and greater than 100 at the same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Mod check will work to make sure that the variable is a whole number:

`If Pcomplete % 1 == 0`, then it is not a decimal number.
Also, the vairbale cannot be both over 100 and less than 0, so seperate them with a ||.

```
if ((Pcomplete == "" ) || (Pcomplete < 0) || (Pcomplete > 100) || (PComplete % 1 !==0) {
  alert('Percentage field is required. You need to type a whole number between 0 and 100');
  return false;
}
```

Comment: `Pcomplete < 0` would fit better i think :)

Answer (score 5):

this will always validate what you want, of course assuming it's a string when provided. Othwerise do value = "" + value or smth.

```
if (/[0-9]/.test(value) && parseInt(value) > 0 && parseInt(value) < 101) {
   // it IS a number, AND its value is between 0 and 100
}
```

Only allow numbers and only numbers between 0 and -100

the regex invalidates comma and dots etc.

Comment: Of course if you want to cast it to an int other options may apply but have strange behaviour

Answer (score 3):

You should change the AND to OR, because you need the range outside.

```
Pcomplete < 0 || Pcomplete > 100
```

```js
function check(Pcomplete) {
    if (Pcomplete === "" || Pcomplete < 0 || Pcomplete > 100 || Pcomplete - Math.floor(Pcomplete)) {
        alert('Percentage field is required. You need to type a number between 0 and 100');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

check('');
check('-1');
check('0.5');
```

Comment: Nice use of '+' to convert string input to int, where string is a valid integer representation :)

Comment: @GrayedFox, but not necessary here. strings became numbers with nonstrict comparisons.

Comment: True. I'm so used to using strict comparisons :) I just noticed, this answer won't catch floating point values however (would need a modulo check for that - example in accepted answer).

Comment: For those interested in performance comparisons between `Math.floor` and `% 1 !== 0` using varied data sets see https://jsfiddle.net/h4kdujkk/. You'll need to be running Chrome, check the console.

Answer (score 1):

- Number from 0 to 100

  ```
  if(number < 0 || number > 100 || Number.isNaN(number)) complain();
  ```
- With no decimal numbers

  ```
  if(!Number.isInteger(number)) complain();
  ```
- No negative numbers: already checked

If your number was a string, convert it to a number:

```
number = +number;
```

But whitespaces will be converted to 0, so before converting check

```
if(number.trim() === '') complain();
```

Comment: Everybody forgets poor `NaN` :(

Answer (score 0):

```
(Pcomplete == "" ) || (Pcomplete < 0 && Pcomplete > 100)
```

The value cannot be < 0 and > 100

```
Pcomplete == ""  || Pcomplete < 0 || Pcomplete > 100 || Pcomplete % 1 !== 0
```

should evaluate

Comment: Thanks all but what about decimal. I don't want to accept something like 25.6%

Comment: @kittenchops suggestion is good for that. Use the mod function. Editing now

Answer (score 0):

```
pcomplete = parseInt(pcomplete)

if (pcomplete && (pcomplete >0 && pcomplete < 100)) {
```

use regex

```
/^[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}$/g.test("88.88")
```

Comment: But that would chop off the invalid decimals

Comment: use regex one line

Comment: So basically use my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a related question, took the code from here (from user Blake Regalia): [How to check if a variable is an integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636536/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-integer-in-javascript)

```
if(typeof data === 'number') {
    var remainder = (data % 1);
    if(remainder === 0) {
        // yes, it is an integer
    }
    else if(isNaN(remainder)) {
        // no, data is either: NaN, Infinity, or -Infinity
    }
    else {
        // no, it is a float (still a number though)
    }
}
else {
    // no way, it is not even a number
}
```

Simplified version:

```
if(typeof data==='number' && (data%1)===0) {
    // data is an integer
}
```

All you need to do is integrate your range validation on either of these blocks