# How can I identify that the variable is a number?

Tags: reactjs

```
if(clientId) var url = BASE_URL+'/projects/task-filter/?client='+clientId+'&offset=0';
  else var url = BASE_URL+'/projects/tasks/?user='+userId+'&offset=0';
```

what should i write in the code if the condition is to check the clientId is a number.have any built function to check the variale is numer or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a variable is an integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636536/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-integer-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the link
https://www.mkyong.com/javascript/check-if-variable-is-a-number-in-javascript/

```
var url = isNaN(clientId) ? BASE_URL+'/projects/task-filter/?client='+clientId+'&offset=0' : BASE_URL+'/projects/tasks/?user='+userId+'&offset=0'
```