# Modify the function to return true if the given number is an integer, and false otherwise

Tags: javascript, xcode, numbers, integer

I am not sure what exactly this question is asking for. Just feeling confused. Please help!

```
function isInteger(num) {

}

/* Do not modify code below this line */

console.log(isInteger(1), '<-- should be true');
console.log(isInteger(1.5), '<-- should be false');
```

when you console log you should get true for the whole number and false for the decimal.

Comment: you need to put code between `function isInteger(num) {` and `}` to satisfy the requirements .. an integer is a whole number, like `1` - a non-integer is a number with a non zero value after the decimal point, like `1.5` - true is `true` and false is `false` - these are the values you need to `return`

Comment: @JaromandaX function isInteger(num) {
if (num === 1) {
  return 'true';
}
return 'false';
}

/* Do not modify code below this line */

console.log(isInteger(1), '<-- should be true');
console.log(isInteger(1.5), '<-- should be false');

Comment: still not working

Comment: You could put this *after* the function right before the "Do not modify" bit: `isInteger = Number.isInteger`

Comment: `1` is the loneliest number, but it isn't the ONLY integer

Answer (score 0):

Look at [How to check if a variable is an integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636536/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-integer-in-javascript) to figure out the logic behind checking if the input is an integer. The simple function I create below returns true if the given number is an integer and false if not.

```js
function isInteger(num) {
  if(num === parseInt(num, 10)){ // checks if input is integer
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

/* Do not modify code below this line */

console.log(isInteger(1), '<-- should be true');
console.log(isInteger(1.5), '<-- should be false');
```