# Sort String containing numbers randomly

Tags: javascript, sorting

So I am trying to implement a sort function in javascript. I have to implement the "compare" function. The main problem is that I don't know whether the user puts pure numbers, partly numbers or only text in his cell.

**Requirement:** I dont know which dataformat the user is using in his row

**Problem:** Following examples after the sort function.

- Data(pure numbers): `1, 10, 2, 3, ...` because it interprets the `10` like `"10"` which comes before "2".
- Data(numbers with unit): `1 m, 10 m, 2 m ...` same problem, but here I can't simply "try" to parse to double
- Data(text): `test1, test10, test2, ...` also wrong sort, not parsable.
- Data(numbers with commas) `1.3 m, 10.3 m, 2.3 m`

Those examples show the data which will be shown wrong. Is the whole column full with text, it works perfect.

**Question:** Is there a way to compare like that existing in javascript, which will treat numbers as such?

```
arrayToSort.sort((a, b) => {
    let valueA = a[key];
    let valueB = b[key];
    return valueB < valueA ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a variable is an integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636536/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-integer-in-javascript)

Comment: actually not :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with options, which applies a natural sorting.

```js
var data = [1, 10, 2, 3, '1 m', '10 m', '2 m', 'test1', 'test10', 'test2', '1.3 m', '10.3 m', '2.3 m', 10.2, 10.3, 10.4];

data.sort((a, b) => a.toString().localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' }))

console.log(data);
```

Comment: It seems like that's what I searched for. Thanks! I knew there has to be something simple from JavaScript.