# Why isNaN('') or isNaN("") is false (one quote or double quotes are considered a valid number)?

Tags: javascript, string

I need a built in function that checks if a variable contains a valid number in Javascript , following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number) I've tried to use is `isNaN` , however when I use one quote ('') or two quotes ("") , the result is always `false`.

How come one quote or double quotes are considered a valid number ?

Comment: Using isNan is not enough to validate a number. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636536/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-integer-in-javascript

Comment: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-isnan-number

Answer (score 1):

[`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

> The empty string is converted to 0 which is not NaN

Answer (score 1):

Any thing which cannot be converted to number should return true, But `""` string can be parsed to number so it returns false

```js
console.log(+"")
console.log(Number(""))
console.log(isNaN(""))
```

A polyfill for [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) looks like this

```js
var isNaN = function(value) {
    var n = Number(value);
    return n !== n;
};

console.log(isNaN(""))
```

Note:- Things get confusing when you try parseInt on these values. But the parseInt specs literally says it returns NaN `the first non-whitespace character cannot be converted to a number.` or `radix is below 2 or above 36`.

```js
console.log(parseInt(""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting an empty string to `Number` will evaluate to 0. Same goes for booleans (`+false` = 0, `+true` = 1), and `null`. If that's unwanted, you can create your own function to determine if some (string) value can be converted to `Number`. See also (the examples @) [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

```js
const canConvert2Number = value =>
      !value ||
      value === false ||
      value === true ||
      value === null || 
      String(value).trim().length < 1
      ? false
      : !isNaN(+value);

console.log(canConvert2Number(null));    //false
console.log(canConvert2Number(""));      //false
console.log(canConvert2Number());        //false
console.log(canConvert2Number(false));   //false
console.log(canConvert2Number(true));    //false
console.log(canConvert2Number("[]"));    //false
console.log(canConvert2Number("{}"));    //false
console.log(canConvert2Number("20.4"));  //true
console.log(canConvert2Number("10E4"));  //true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```