# How can I check if x is an integer in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I check if x is an integer in javascript?

- 1 -> OK
- 11 -> OK
- 1.1 -> not OK (decimal place)
- null -> not OK (null)
- a -> not OK (letter)
- 1e1 -> not OK (letter)
- 1 1 -> not OK (sapce in any position (include front or end))

  ```
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["numofquestions"].value;    

  if (x==null || x=="" || isNaN(x) || x<1 || x>500 || (x%1 != 0)) {
     alert("Please fill in number between 1 - 1000");
  }
  ```

Comment: This post might help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323314/how-to-detect-if-a-given-number-is-an-integer

Comment: The value can't be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your value to an integer and check if this number is equal to your value:

```
parseInt(n) === n;
```

Comment: @undefined No, why should it fail? A string gets converted to a number (or NaN), and if this doesn't match to the input-value it will be falsy and everything is ok...

Comment: I had removed my comment, but I repeat it, this won't work. `parseInt('1')` is not strictly equal to `'1'`.

Comment: @undefined: Which is OK, isn't it? `'1'` is not an integer, it's a string.

Comment: @FelixKling Well, `x` in the question refers to a form input's value, which is a string. OP is validating user inputs.

Answer (score 0):

to check you can use

```
n % 1 === 0
```