# How can I validate if a given number is integer or not in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation, if-statement, input

I'm currently validating a form with JavaScript in which the user has to type their id number . I already figure out how to validate if the value is numeric, but I'm struggling to find a way to validate if the given number is integer or not.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/isInteger

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check that a number is float or integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-do-i-check-that-a-number-is-float-or-integer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect if a given number is an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323314/how-to-detect-if-a-given-number-is-an-integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Number.isInteger(Number(input))
```

Comment: @JoséCañizales let's accept this answer if it's helpful for you.

Comment: Note about integer range with `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. Let's see more about [Grandes enteros en JavaScript](https://codesearchable.com/es/4134437/)